# PySpark: lasso returns all coefficients non-zero

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, logistic-regression

After splitting my data in to training and testing, my training data has about 33 million records. I have 77 features and a binary response. I am fitting a logistic regression with lasso. However, lasso returns non-zero coefficient values for all the columns. I explored the correlation of the features among themselves and some of them have correlation of up to 0.8 and 0.7. Provided that I have many features (77) and the features are correlated, I would expect lasso to filter out at least some of the features. Why is this not happening? I could not share the data because of its size and privacy. But the code I am using is below. I am looking for what could be happening and what to explore.

```
logreg = LogisticRegression(maxIter = 200, featuresCol = "features", 
                 labelCol = 'label', standardization = True, elasticNetParam = 1)
paramGrid_logreg = ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(logreg.regParam, np.linspace(0.0, 1, 11)).build()
crossval_logreg = CrossValidator(estimator = logreg, 
                                 estimatorParamMaps = paramGrid_logreg, 
                                 evaluator = BinaryClassificationEvaluator(), 
                                 numFolds = 10) 
cvModel_logreg = crossval_logreg.fit(train_df)
```

Now, the coefficients are below:

```
cvModel_logreg.bestModel.coefficients
```

> DenseVector([0.0022, -0.0216, -0.0261, -0.0018, 0.0014, -0.0012, -0.0006, 0.0023, -0.0024, -0.0003, -0.0114, 0.0003, 0.0, -0.0018, -0.0163, -0.0009, -0.0022, 0.0009, -0.0017, 0.0005, -0.0024, 0.0006, -0.0025, 0.0015, -0.0025, 0.0007, -0.002, 0.0002, 0.0007, 0.0002, -0.0025, 0.0008, -0.0012, -0.0001, -0.0017, 0.0002, 0.0026, -0.0002, -0.0019, 0.0003, -0.0017, 0.0005, -0.0019, 0.0008, -0.0023, 0.0008, -0.0021, -0.0003, -0.0021, 0.0011, -0.0019, 0.0003, -0.0018, -0.0006, 0.0001, -0.0009, -0.3818, -0.0425, -0.0065, 0.0014, 0.1304, 0.0003, -0.0698, 0.0002, 0.0005, 0.0014, 0.0161, -0.0005, 0.0099, 0.0003, 0.051, -0.0006, -0.0001, -0.0005, 0.3291, -0.0056, 0.0451])

Comment: what is optimized value of regParam coming out of cross validation

Comment: cvModel_logreg_lasso4.bestModel._java_obj.getRegParam() gives 0.0

Comment: that means zero Lasso penalty. If you want lesser number of variables then you must have some penalty there but CV is saying best model is with zero penalty. Analyze CV results and decide.